# How to lookup with composite key in IndexedDB using Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, progressive-web-apps, indexeddb

I have IndexedDB store with a composite key `['path', 'frame']`. What I should type in '*Start from key*' field to lookup for certain items? I use Chrome browser.

[image: IDB screenshot]

Comment: Try `['img/exrc/ankle/005', '036']`